# Attach totalview debugger to a variable

Tags: c, debugging, totalview

So I am trying to debug a code. But for some reason it doesn't pass through the section I need it to. The governing variable which calls the piece of code is a pointer "*sret". I tried a lot but with no luck. Its a C program. Is there a way I can attach a watch point on a variable? as it wouldn't recognize the variable...It recognizes the file though.

Answer (score 0):

@Ban,

If you are using the TotalView debugger then this is a great question. Yes, we do provide watchpoints. However, they are set on  memory locations, as opposed to variables. This distinction is important because if you imagine a function that calls itself recursively and a local variable X in that function. You can run the program to that function, dive on X and set a watchpoint on it. The watchpoint will trigger if that specific instance of X (which points to that memory location in the stack) is written to. We won't stop if, for example, the function calls itself again (which effectively creates a new, distinct, X at a different location in the stack) and that second X is written to.

Some other capabilities you might find useful:

- You can set the value of your variable directly in the debugger. You can use this to verify that if the variable has the "right" value the program will behave as you expect it.
- You can step instruction by instruction over the part of the program where you expect that it should make the decision to go down the code path you are looking for it to get into. Displaying both the source and assembly code is useful for this kind of debugging.
- If you are on the linux-x86-64 platform you may find the ReplayEngine capability helpful. This lets you run forwards and backwards through your program -- which might help you really narrow in on exactly what is happening to keep your program from doing what you want.

Let me know how you get on with debugging this problem. If you found your solution some other way I'd be curious about that as well.

Good luck!

Chris Gottbrath

Principal Product Manager for TotalView at Rogue Wave Software

email: first dot last at roguewave dot com